# Stack Exchange site with most Hindi speakers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, languages

On which Stack Exchange sites do I have a chance to find some Hindi speakers? Or people interested in Hindi?

I've tried [a tag search](https://stackexchange.com/filters/176083/hindi), but it didn't help because apparently the tag only exists on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The tag now exists on https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hindi too, with 4 questions, but I think the point stands. :)

Answer (score 9):

If you are interested in the language itself, the [Indian Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67907/hindi-language) proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is something you really want to follow.

Else there might be a chat room in the site of your choice where you can find Hindi speakers.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about those proposals. It seems a egg vs. chicken issue though, how can those proposals reach Hindi speakers if the proposals themselves are the only way to identify them? :)

Comment: @Nemo remember, Stack Exchange is not social media.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Just please, please don't make comments one of those communication channels. Some people have spammed Area 51 site proposals across hundreds of questions on Stack Overflow, and that gets incredibly annoying.

Comment: @brad sorry. My bad.

Comment: So sad. Those proposal are deleted now!